# why is training a model taking so long?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am an absolute beginner in tensorflow. I am trying to run the program https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner on my ASUS Laptop. It has Ryzen 9 CPU and NVIDIA RTX 3070 GPU.

But it is taking more than a few hours now. And I haven't seen anything like this anywhere. I dont know what is going on here.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()
tf.nn.softmax(predictions).numpy()
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
loss_fn(y_train[:1], predictions).numpy()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

After this line, the log should be like this:

```
Epoch 1/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2956 - accuracy: 0.9137
Epoch 2/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1430 - accuracy: 0.9572
Epoch 3/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1059 - accuracy: 0.9682
Epoch 4/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0870 - accuracy: 0.9736
Epoch 5/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0732 - accuracy: 0.9774
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fabfe6f6cd0>
```

But it is not anywhere near like the log shown above and it is taking forever. I can sense that something is wrong here. THis is the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-fBCE9bC3sFUkdRSV73H7bDYrNUdXKxy/view?usp=sharing

#### Update

---

I am now using pycharm on my laptop. And here it took only 18 seconds to finish training. Earlier I used IDLE, and it took forever. Why it is making such a huge difference, I don't know. But here is the log:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\PycharmProjects\tensorflow\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ASUS/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/main.py
TensorFlow version:  2.7.0
2021-11-12 14:50:35.916573: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-11-12 14:50:36.233533: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5486 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
2021-11-12 14:50:37.041462: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1774] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
Epoch 1/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2929 - accuracy: 0.9148
Epoch 2/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1435 - accuracy: 0.9571
Epoch 3/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1078 - accuracy: 0.9670
Epoch 4/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0868 - accuracy: 0.9737
Epoch 5/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 5s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0740 - accuracy: 0.9768

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Instead of using idle (is suppose on your local machine?) I suggest you try out google [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) for practicing.
Note that on the TensorFlow example pages there is [usually the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDN4L.png) If you click it colab opens and you could then create a copy of the example in your own google drive and play around with it in colab. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inN8seMm7UI) might be a good starting point on using colab.

Comment: yes, I am running it on my laptop. So is this because my laptop is too slow for this?

Comment: I tried it on colab as you said. And it trained withing 2 seconds! But in my laptop, with Ryzen 9 cpu and RTX 3070 GPU, it took so many hours. I am a little discouraged now.

Comment: Does tensorflow actually use your GPU? Check `train_x.device` and (not sure if it works) `model.device`. If it says something like `...CPU:0` your RTX might be slacking ;-). You can use the [TF GPU Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) for guidance on GPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in speed has nothing to do with the IDE. There can be several reasons for this:

1. You must be running with different versions of Tensorflow. In some older versions of tensorflow versions you need to mention the GPU otherwise it uses CPU to train your model.
2. Maybe PyCharm and IDLE are running on different versions of Python